# Saving a datatable to an Azure container

Tags: c#, azure

I have a need to archive data in a SQL Server table into an Azure container.

The container is called Core-Backups and I connect to the container like so:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("snip");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Core-Backups");
```

I would like the data I am archiving to go into a folder structure like

```
tablename/year/month/day/hour
```

And I have some questions

```
1. Do I need to create all of the folder structure first, or does Azure create it when I upload content? Right now my container is empty

2. Is there a standard way to save a datatable to an Azure blob?
```

For a test I tried the following code to upload a text file into an example of the folder structure I want but it failed with a {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("Core-Backups");
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("table1/2017/04/24/9/file1.txt");
blob.UploadText("lorem ipsum");
```

Edit: I just read that containers must follow DNS rules, so I changed the GetContainerReference line to "core-backups" and it worked.

However question 2 remains, is there a recommended way to upload a datatable?

Comment: I wouldn't use a DataTable at all. That's a .NET idea. Use some common format that anything can understand and that can better represent the structure of your data. JSON, XML etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading DataTable to Azure blob storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305800/uploading-datatable-to-azure-blob-storage)