# How to upload stream with Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I’m trying to upload/store data into an azure blob. The data is generated from a xmlSerialize object. Since the result can be big and I don’t need the serialized output in my program I would like to stream the data directly into the blob. 
This has been solved with [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/)  : 
[uploading-datatable-to-azure-blob-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305800/uploading-datatable-to-azure-blob-storage)
But I’m using [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs) since Microsoft is recommending it and the other has been replaced. Also it supports auth with Identity.

The previews solution relied on getting the stream object for the blob so it could be used by the serializer. But I don’t see any way to do the same with the new API. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395088/2589083

> new Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient(System.Uri uri)

Answer (score 2):

> But I don’t see any way to do the same with the new API. Am I missing
>   something?

You're correct. Getting a stream object for the blob is not available in the new SDK. You will need to convert the data into stream and then use `Upload` or `UploadAsync` method on [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_Upload_System_IO_Stream_) or [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlockBlobClient_Upload_System_IO_Stream_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobHttpHeaders_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Nullable_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_AccessTier__System_IProgress_System_Int64__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to upload the blob.

Comment: "You will need to convert the data into stream" you mean storing the result in a MemoryStream or write it into a temp file?

Comment: Storing it in memory stream.

Comment: Or if you want you can save it in a file. Then you can read the file in chunks and upload them using methods available in `BlockBlobClient`.

Comment: It's possible through IBinder coming from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs events though.

using (var sw = binder.Bind<Stream>(new BlobAttribute(blobNameOut, FileAccess.Write)))
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sw))
                        {
                            await WriteMethod(streamReader, writer, cancellationToken);
                        }
If you know if it's possible to instantiate IBinder with any implementation I'm interested :)